# irreducible polynomial X in residue class

Tags: abstract-algebra

I wanted to ask if my thinking is right: the polynomial $X$ is reducible in the residue class ring 2 $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$, as $X=XX$, a nontrivial factorization. is this right?

Comment: It is not true that $\;x^2=x\;$ for $\;x,x^2\in\left(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\right)[x]\;$ . Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: I was thinking if x = 0 x^2=0, if x=1 x^2=1?! same function no?

Comment: Polynomials are not the same as polynomial functions!

Comment: As darij wrote @user179546, you're confusing (formally defined) polynomials, as in the ring of polynomials over some ring or fields, say, and *polynomial functions*

Answer (score 1):

For finite fields the map from  $F[x]$ to (functions $\colon F \to F$ ) is not injective.  As you observed, on $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$  the polynomials $x$ and $x^2$ give the same functions  on $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. However, the polynomials $x$ and $x^2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$ are not equal.

Comment: For finite or infinite fields, or rings or whatever, there's an acute difference between polynomial and polynomial-functions

Comment: It is your very first sentence that seems to me confusing, as it seems to hint that in the infinite fields' case it may be otherwise. It is not: in *any* case there's an important distinction between pol's and pol. functions.

Comment: Either I'm not explaining myself correctly or you're simply having a point I don't get: you wrote "for finite fields there's a difference..." and etc. I'm remarking here that difference is **not** only "for finite fields" but for **any** field, ring or whaever, finite or otherwise. What you probably want to say, and it is not connected in my opinion, with the above, is that in the finite case some polynomial **functions** can be identical to other polynomial functions without the respective coefficients being equal and etc.

Comment: I think this time is fine @orangeskid, though the basic nature of the question perhaps points towards the possibility the OP won't fully understand the idea of that map, injevtivity and etc. Anyway though, I think it is accurate now. +1